# npm/yarn install package from a non-root git repo

Tags: git, npm, yarnpkg

for example a repot called `my-tools` has two npm packages `tool-A` and `tool-B`, as directories under `my-tools` repo.

if I want to add those two packages with npm, what url should I use?

I tried things like

```
yarn add https://github.com/xxx/my-tools.git/tool-A
yarn add https://github.com/xxx/my-tools/tool-A.git
```

but non of them works.